# JavaScript IF (loginSuccess) DO (...)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables, conditional-statements

The title may be misleading, however, I don't know how to phrase it exactly.

What I'm trying to achieve is a response of the correct login details from the provided list and to stop when one set of credentials is correct (see the commented out portion of code).

My issue is that I have no idea what the variable is that determines a successful login, so my question is: how do I find that variable?

In this example from [CyberStart Game](https://game.joincyberdiscovery.com/), when the correct credentials are inputted it will relay a flag (a string of characters) in the green area at the top.  Running this code, the green box appears but no flag is presented.  My theory is that the code is continuing to run after the correct credentials are inputted and it messes up the display of the flag.  *NOTE: There is only one set of successful login credentials.*

```
var usrnmPswd = [
["CarlottaCarrigan", "HULUGOLFPARK"], 
["Horace-Heideman", "yelpvisa99"],
["Delfina_Detwiler", "12345"],
["AhmedAlper", "PASS_word77"],
["Annabell+Allred", "hatsaregreat"],
["aspen_van_whistlethorn", "cyclepower1999"],
["LaquandaLoy99", "LLLLPASS"],
["Liza_Van_Lundahl123", "password"],
["KentKastner", "somethinghere"],
["EarnestineEllman", "EarnyPass"],
["KimbraKyles", "KimPassword"],
["Lois-Lokey", "12345"],
["Louis@Larimore", "passwords_4eva"],
["Cornell=Clausing", "gogoSECURITY!"],
["DuaneDendy99", "99passwords"],
];

for (var i=0; i <= usrnmPswd.length; i++) {
    attemptLogin(usrnmPswd[i+1][0],usrnmPswd[i+1][1]);
    //if (loginSuccessful) {
    //    return (usrnmPswd[i+1][0],usrnmPswd[i+1][1]);
    //    break;
    //};
};
```

Any ideas of how I can check if a "login success" has occurred?

[image: CyberStart Game example.]

`attemptLogin()` partially deobfuscated code via [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/RUSahfUY)

Comment: can you post the attemptLogin() function too? Also, if the code continues running after a successful match, it sounds like you need a break; in the loop after the match is found.

Comment: So what is `attemptLogin`?  My guess is something is asynchronous and you are not going to be using a loop for this unless you are using await/async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var usrnmPswd = [
["CarlottaCarrigan", "HULUGOLFPARK"], 
["Horace-Heideman", "yelpvisa99"],
["Delfina_Detwiler", "12345"],
["AhmedAlper", "PASS_word77"],
["Annabell+Allred", "hatsaregreat"],
["aspen_van_whistlethorn", "cyclepower1999"],
["LaquandaLoy99", "LLLLPASS"],
["Liza_Van_Lundahl123", "password"],
["KentKastner", "somethinghere"],
["EarnestineEllman", "EarnyPass"],
["KimbraKyles", "KimPassword"],
["Lois-Lokey", "12345"],
["Louis@Larimore", "passwords_4eva"],
["Cornell=Clausing", "gogoSECURITY!"],
["DuaneDendy99", "99passwords"],
];

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function testAuth() {
   for (var i = 0; i < usrnmPswd.length; i++) {
      attemptLogin(usrnmPswd[i][0], usrnmPswd[i][1]);
      await sleep(100);
      if (document.getElementById("msg-correct").innerHTML.includes("Success!")) {
          console.log(document.getElementById("msg-correct").innerHTML);  
          return usrnmPswd[i,0];
      };
   };
};

testAuth();
```

Thank you to Nicholas Smith for suggesting to make it a function and check the ID of an HTML element for this use-case.

Turns out it was reiterating too quickly, not allowing for verification of user credentials and it would end up skipping each query entirely.

The fix was to simply create a "wait until" function to give the server time to confirm the credentials.  Thanks for the help!

[image: CyberStart Game Example]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're attempting to access an index that is outside the size of the array. You see, when `for (var i = 0; i < usrnmPswd.length)`, the variable `i` is the index of the current item in the array. Your code is iterating through the next item as opposed to the current item. At the end of the array, you can see that you're actually accessing `usernPswd[usernmPswd.length + 1]`, which doesn't exist. This causes the TypeError you're experiencing.

You should do it this way:

```
var usrnmPswd = [
["CarlottaCarrigan", "HULUGOLFPARK"], 
["Horace-Heideman", "yelpvisa99"],
["Delfina_Detwiler", "12345"],
["AhmedAlper", "PASS_word77"],
["Annabell+Allred", "hatsaregreat"],
["aspen_van_whistlethorn", "cyclepower1999"],
["LaquandaLoy99", "LLLLPASS"],
["Liza_Van_Lundahl123", "password"],
["KentKastner", "somethinghere"],
["EarnestineEllman", "EarnyPass"],
["KimbraKyles", "KimPassword"],
["Lois-Lokey", "12345"],
["Louis@Larimore", "passwords_4eva"],
["Cornell=Clausing", "gogoSECURITY!"],
["DuaneDendy99", "99passwords"],
];

function testAuth(){
   for (var i = 0; i < usrnmPswd.length; i++) {
       var loginSuccessful = attemptLogin(usrnmPswd[i][0], usrnmPswd[i][1]);
       if (document.getElementById("msg-incorrect").innerHTML.includes("Success!")){
         console.log(usrnmPswd[i]);  
         return usrnmPswd[i];
       };
   }
}

testAuth();
```

P.S. You don't exactly need a `break` statement here, a break statement is only used if you need to skip over an item in an array. In this instance since there is only one correct credential, you don't need to continue running the code after you've found the correct pair. `return` completely stops the `for` loop all together.

Comment: Thank you.  This fixes the TypeError, however, I still need to figure out how to stop the iteration once the correct credential set has been input.  `loginSuccessful` is just a placeholder for a variable or server response to check for in order to stop the loop.  I get `Illegal return statement` currently.

Comment: @Regiment Is there anywhere we can test this code to work? Btw what does attemptLogin return? Is it only a true or false value?

Comment: It returns `undefined`, but it displays "Sorry, your username and password are incorrect" on the page.  Unfortunately, the only way to access CyberStart is if you're in the UK and complete CyberStart Assess.  Not the most ideal example I suppose.

`<div class="flash flash-centered flash-error" style="display: block;" id="msg-incorrect">Sorry, your username or password are incorrect</div>`

Comment: I see. You could try to check if it doesn't return undefined to return the correct credentials. Something like `if (loginSuccessful !== null) return usernmPswd[i]`

Comment: @Regiment Just saw your comment about the illegal return statement. See the updated return statement in the answer

Comment: Every `return` statement comes back as illegal.  Hm.

Comment: @Regiment - please try the edited code above. Looks like the code comes back as illegal since we're using it outside a function.

Comment: No more illegalities!  Yay.  However, it is now returning `undefined`.

Comment: I see. Apologies I forgot to include the if statement checks if the variable is undefined or not. Try the code above. Btw are you still getting the message that the credentials are incorrect? What message is being received now?

Comment: With the check, it is hitting the first set of credentials and stopping.  Without the check, it hits the right credential set and displays the green flag box with no flag and then continues, resulting in an incorrect login message.

Comment: What if instead of trying to find what this mystery is that we're checking for, how can I check when a piece of HTML/CSS is being displayed?  Something along the lines of `if (errorDisplayed) { continue; };` but how would I do this?  The error's ID is `msg-incorrect`.

Comment: Here's a PasteBin for the HTML: https://pastebin.com/vpuq1YiY

Comment: Do you know the exact message it should say if the login is successful?

Comment: At the start, it is: `<div class="captured" style="display: none;" id="msg-correct"></div>` but once the correct credentials are input it becomes `<div class="captured" style="display: block;" id="msg-correct">Success! The flag is DTCFXNQCNATB</div>` .  Something is updating it from the "Log in" button, but it may be obfuscated or is done externally.  The flag is not within the source code, obviously.

Comment: The answer now includes the returning of the value, as well as a console.log so you can actually see the answer in the console.

Comment: The `console.log` is not showing anything, returning `undefined`, and `msg-correct` is displaying as a block, so the green box pops up, but the text is not being updated for some reason.

Comment: I've done some more experimenting and have found that if the correct set of credentials is at the end of the array, "msg-correct" updates with the flag, so my initial suspicion was correct in thinking its the continuation of the iteration that's messing something up.  Maybe it's going too quickly for the page to verify and it ends up skipping it, resulting in a half response (just the green box), and not the flag.